# Where are Mass Effect 3 saved games located on PC?

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc

I'm looking to back up by saved games from Mass Effect 3, but I cannot locate them.

Where are the Mass Effect 3 saved game files stored?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default save location is in the `BioWare\Mass Effect 3\Save` directory, inside of your My Documents folder. There will be individual folders for character you have, which contain all of the saves associated with that character.